# Map sap:quickinfo into generated Java entity with odata-core

Tags: odata, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-gateway

I create an OData client from an EDMX file using `com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel.odata-core`
(https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java).

My EDMX file contains the properties with `sap:quickinfo` values like

```
<Property Name="NAME" sap:label="C-Name" sap:heading="CUST" sap:quickinfo="Customer Name" [...] >
```

The generated fields looks like this

```
    @SerializedName("NAME")
    @JsonProperty("NAME")
    @Nullable
    @ODataField(odataName = "NAME")
    private String nAME;
```

and **I need an additional annotation like `@Quickinfo("Customer Name")`.**

**Is there any way I can get this quickinfo mapped into an annotation to the generated entity?**

I use this parameters for the generator:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel</groupId>
                <artifactId>odata-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.52.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-consumption</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputDirectory>${project.basedir}/sap/</inputDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/sap/</outputDirectory>
                            <deleteOutputDirectory>true</deleteOutputDirectory>
                            <packageName>app.customers</packageName>
                            <defaultBasePath>sap/opu/odata/SAP/</defaultBasePath>
                            <compileScope>COMPILE</compileScope>
                            <serviceMethodsPerEntitySet>false</serviceMethodsPerEntitySet>
                            <nameSource>NAME</nameSource>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you would like to use that attribute for?

Comment: My client application which calls the OData API does not now about the meaning of the SAP labels but only knows the strings in sap:quickinfo. Therefore I need a mapping between the quickinfo values and labels (getters).
I solved it by creating the mapping manually. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**
I'm a member of the SAP Cloud SDK for Java development team.

The [SAP Cloud SDK's OpenApi generator](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/generate-rest-client) is a wrapper of the open source [OpenApi Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) (we are using version `5.0.0-beta3`).
Therefore, our wrapper supports only features that are also supported by the mentioned open source variant.

Unfortunately, creating arbitrary `Attribute` classes for properties of the service specification is not a supported feature as of now.